# Total quantity for each Distinct names

Tags: mysql, sql

```
user1 90 add
user2 60 remove
user3 70 remove
user2 80 remove
user2 80 remove
user1 70 remove
user3 20 add
user4 10 add
```

I need the sql query to get the total for each user. In this case for `user1 i should get 20` for

```
user4 --> 10
user3 --> -50
```

I have tried :

```
SELECT description, SUM( money ) FROM jabeda GROUP BY description
```

How to do this?

Comment: SELECT description, SUM( money ) 
FROM  `jabeda` 
GROUP BY description

Comment: this code taken from actual table

Comment: `user3` should be `90`. right?

Comment: For completeness, please add the create table statement.

Comment: yes u are right sorry about that @491243

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  col1, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN col3 = 'add' THEN col2 ELSE col2 * -1 END) TOtals
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY col1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc568/1)

I'm not sure about the names of your columns but the query will certainly help you. `Col1` which is the name of the `user`. `Col2` is the amount while `Col3` is some what the action type.

What the query does is check the type whether it is `add` or `remove`. When it happens to be `remove`, the value is multiplied by `-1` to negate the value.

Comment: Slightly more compact version: `SELECT col1, SUM(col2 * IF(col3 = 'add', 1, -1)) AS Totals FROM tableName GROUP BY col1`

Comment: @neubert yep compact version but it's vendor specific. `CASE` will work mostly on any other RDBMS.

Comment: even with `case` i'd write this like `col2 * case col3 when 'add' then 1 when 'remove' then -1 end` - so I won't repeat col2

Comment: why dont u post it as answer @neubert

Comment: @LynAs you may want to add this index KEY(col1) to remove the need off "Using temporary; Using filesort" these are performance killers for MySQL when the tables are large